# Display server message on initial redux-form load

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I need to have a redux-form-toaster message display on the first click of my submit button when the form first loads. The toaster message displays on the second click of the submit button. I know there's a component life-cycle issue that I need to address but I can't seem to pin it down.

Here is my register.js file:

```javascript
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/auth';
import Notifications, {notify} from 'react-notify-toast';
import Input from '../common/Input';

const form = reduxForm({
  form: 'register',
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password'],
  validate
});

const selector = formValueSelector('register');

function validate(formProps) {
  const errors = {};

  if (!formProps.firstName) {
    errors.firstName = 'Please enter a first name';
  }

  if (!formProps.lastName) {
    errors.lastName = 'Please enter a last name';
  }

  if (!formProps.email) {
    errors.email = 'Please enter an email';
  } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(formProps.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address format';
  }

  if (!formProps.password) {
    errors.password = 'Please enter a password';
  }

  return errors;
}


class Register extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.registerUser(formProps);
  }

  renderServerAlert() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div>
          {notify.show(this.props.errorMessage, 'error', 5000)}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { email, handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="middle-box text-center loginscreen" style={{position: 'absolute', top: -30, marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto', left: 0, right: 0}}>
          <h2 style={{fontWeight: 500}} className="text-muted">Register</h2>
            <Notifications />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
              <Field name="firstName" component={Input} type="text" label="Firstname" />
              <Field name="lastName" component={Input} type="text" label="Lastname" />
              <Field name="email" component={Input} type="text" label="Email" />
              <Field name="password" component={Input} type="password" label="Password" />
              <button action="submit" disabled={submitting} onClick={() => {this.renderServerAlert()}} className="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>
          <p className="text-muted text-center">Already have an account?</p>
              <Link className="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" to="/login">Login</Link>
            </form>
            <p className="m-t"> MyCopany Business Application Starter &copy; 2017 </p>
        </div>
        <div className="footer" style={{zIndex: 999, position: 'fixed', bottom: 0}}>
          <div className="pull-right">
            <strong>MyCompany</strong> Always Free.
          </div>
          <div>
            <strong>Copyright</strong> MyCompany &copy; 2016-2017
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.auth.error,
    message: state.auth.message,
    authenticated: state.auth.authenticated
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { registerUser })(form(Register));
```

Here are my auth.js actions file:

```javascript
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import { API_URL, CLIENT_ROOT_URL, errorHandler } from './index';
import { AUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR,  UNAUTH_USER, FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST, RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST, PROTECTED_TEST } from './types';

//================================
// Authentication actions
//================================

// TO-DO: Add expiration to cookie
export function loginUser({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, { email, password })
    .then(response => {
      cookie.save('token', response.data.token, { path: '/' });
      cookie.save('user', response.data.user, { path: '/' });
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
      window.location.href = CLIENT_ROOT_URL + '/dashboard';
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
    });
    }
  }

export function registerUser({ email, firstName, lastName, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/register`, { email, firstName, lastName, password })
    .then(response => {
      cookie.save('token', response.data.token, { path: '/' });
      cookie.save('user', response.data.user, { path: '/' });
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
      window.location.href = CLIENT_ROOT_URL + '/dashboard';
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
    });
  }
}

export function logoutUser(error) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: UNAUTH_USER });
    cookie.remove('token', { path: '/' });
    cookie.remove('user', { path: '/' });

    window.location.href = CLIENT_ROOT_URL + '/login';
  }
}

export function getForgotPasswordToken({ email }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/forgot-password`, { email })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
        payload: response.data.message
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
    });
  }
}

export function resetPassword( token, { password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/reset-password/${token}`, { password })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
        payload: response.data.message
      });
      // Redirect to login page on successful password reset
      browserHistory.push('/login');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
    });
  }
}

export function protectedTest() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${API_URL}/protected`, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': cookie.load('token') }
    })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: PROTECTED_TEST,
        payload: response.data.content
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
    });
  }
}
```

...and lastly here is the server-side controller:

```js
"use strict";

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
      crypto = require('crypto'),
      User = require('../models/user'),
      mailgun = require('../config/mailgun'),
      mailchimp = require('../config/mailchimp'),
      config = require('../config/main');

// Generate JWT
// TO-DO Add issuer and audience
function generateToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
    expiresIn: 10080 // in seconds
  });
}

// Set user info from request
function setUserInfo(request) {
  let getUserInfo = {
    _id: request._id,
    firstName: request.profile.firstName,
    lastName: request.profile.lastName,
    email: request.email,
    role: request.role,
  };

  return getUserInfo;
}

//========================================
// Login Route
//========================================
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {

  let userInfo = setUserInfo(req.user);

  res.status(200).json({
    token: 'JWT ' + generateToken(userInfo),
    user: userInfo
  });
}


//========================================
// Registration Route
//========================================
exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
  // Check for registration errors
  const email = req.body.email;
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // Return error if no email provided
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address.'});
  }

  // Return error if full name not provided
  if (!firstName || !lastName) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter your full name.'});
  }

  // Return error if no password provided
  if (!password) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter a password.' });
  }

  User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, existingUser) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      // If user is not unique, return error
      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(422).send({ error: 'Email address already exists.' });
      }

      // If email is unique and password was provided, create account
      let user = new User({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        profile: { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName }
      });

      user.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        // Subscribe member to Mailchimp list
        // mailchimp.subscribeToNewsletter(user.email);

        // Respond with JWT if user was created

        let userInfo = setUserInfo(user);

        res.status(201).json({
          token: 'JWT ' + generateToken(userInfo),
          user: userInfo
        });
      });
  });
}

//========================================
// Authorization Middleware
//========================================

// Role authorization check
exports.roleAuthorization = function(role) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    const user = req.user;

    User.findById(user._id, function(err, foundUser) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(422).json({ error: 'No user was found.' });
        return next(err);
      }

      // If user is found, check role.
      if (foundUser.role == role) {
        return next();
      }

      res.status(401).json({ error: 'You are not authorized to view this content.' });
      return next('Unauthorized');
    })
  }
}

//========================================
// Forgot Password Route
//========================================

exports.forgotPassword = function(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email;

  User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, existingUser) {
    // If user is not found, return error
    if (err || existingUser == null) {
      res.status(422).json({ error: 'Your request could not be processed as entered. Please try again.' });
      return next(err);
    }

      // If user is found, generate and save resetToken

      // Generate a token with Crypto
      crypto.randomBytes(48, function(err, buffer) {
        const resetToken = buffer.toString('hex');
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        existingUser.resetPasswordToken = resetToken;
        existingUser.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        existingUser.save(function(err) {
          // If error in saving token, return it
          if (err) { return next(err); }

          const message = {
            subject: 'Reset Password',
            text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
            'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
            'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset-password/' + resetToken + '\n\n' +
            'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
          }

          // Otherwise, send user email via Mailgun
          mailgun.sendEmail(existingUser.email, message);

          res.status(200).json({ message: 'Please check your email for the link to reset your password.'});
          next();
        });
      });
  });
}

//========================================
// Reset Password Route
//========================================

exports.verifyToken = function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, resetUser) {

    // If query returned no results, token expired or was invalid. Return error.
      if(!resetUser) {
        res.status(422).json({ error: 'Your token has expired. Please attempt to reset your password again.' });
      }

      // Otherwise, save new password and clear resetToken from database
      resetUser.password = req.body.password;
      resetUser.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
      resetUser.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

      resetUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        // If password change saved successfully, alert user via email
        const message = {
          subject: 'Password Changed',
          text: 'You are receiving this email because you changed your password. \n\n' +
          'If you did not request this change, please contact us immediately.'
        }

        // Otherwise, send user email confirmation of password change via Mailgun
        mailgun.sendEmail(resetUser.email, message);

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Password changed successfully. Please login with your new password.'});
        next();
      });
  });
}
```

Everything works perfect (on second click)

Answer (score 1):

it is not a code problem, If you use a debugger you will notice Redux React is hitting the wrong local host for the back end

xhr.js:173 POST http://localhost:3000/api/XXX 401 (Unauthorized) .  that's why you getting the error